# ajax without returning from server and get 500 error

Tags: php, ajax, nginx, yii2

I am using Yii2 for backend code and a the following function:

```
public function actionPrechecklist()
{
    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    $post = Yii::$app->request->post('checklist_content');
    if ($post) {
        $session->set('checklists_content', $post);
    }
}
```

without return. Then I make an ajax request to this function. And it works on localhost. But when I push my code to droplet (VPS) with nginx server with right configuration ( I'm sure that because else things are working correctly) I got an error with status is 500

Then I added return true; to the function above and it's working correctly. So could you guys please explain why?

Comment: Look at php logs - maybe you not installed some php module that needed for yii2, maybe there some problem with permissions, maybe something else.

Comment: Please add your 500 "internal server error" log